# Ember refresh route on form submit

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've a form in one of the ember routes when submitted i need to fresh only that,

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
      submit: function(e){
        var comment = this.get("ncomment");
        this.set("ncomment","");
        var self = this;
       $.post('/api/comment.php' , {comment : comment})
        .done(function(){
            self.refresh();
       });
      }
}
});
```

This code is giving me an error **TypeError: self.refresh is not a function**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter again on same route with same model you need to call `Em.Route.refresh` method on that route. To do it from `Em.Controller` you need to access to that route. Usually, you can do it by `this.get('target')` (inside controller). Then, controller must `send` action to route: `this.get('target').send('actionName')` (that action must be in actions hash of the route).

Complete example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    refresh: function() {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    ref: function(){
      this.get('target').send('refresh');
    }
  }
});
```

[jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/makeci/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

Have a action on PostRoute that calls route's refresh() method and call that action from the controller.

Something like this.

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
      submit: function(e){
        var comment = this.get("ncomment");
        this.set("ncomment","");
        var self = this;
       $.post('/api/comment.php' , {comment : comment})
        .done(function(){
            self.send('refreshRoute');
       });
      }
 }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
   refreshRoute:function(){
    this.refresh()
   }
  }
});
```